# Firebase NextJS deployment not serving static images

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have finally uploaded my `NextJS` project to `Firebase Hosting` but non of the static images are showing on my site (404). They seem to be requested from this URL:
`https://<PROJECTID>.web.app/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo.d526d819.png&w=640&q=75`
I can see that the `.firebase` deployment folder has a `.next/static/media` folder with all the images in it. And I can view the images from the URL: `https://<projectID>.web.app/_next/static/media/logo.d526d819.png` so I think it has to do with the `Image` component and the URL param not being relative.

I tried this to see if I could get it serving the images from the `assets/images` folder instead: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5944 - but it didn't make any difference, and I was already importing my images this way anyway.

It has put the video assets into the `assets/videos` folder, and these run on the website. In `React` these aren't imports, though, and are just pointing to the `public` folder.
Is there a way to do the same with the `images` folder?

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your next.config.js folder:

```js
images: {
   unoptimized: true
}
```

If your project's static images not show after deploy on firebase then it can be helpful.